# scrolling on inner div doesn't scroll outer div?

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, scroll

I have a page set up for mobile like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zhm69/1/

I wanted to be able to scroll the 'outer-wrapper' left/right when in the 'scrollable-div', however at the moment nothing happens (which is annoying as each of my 'inner-divs' are basically pages which cover the whole screen, so I would like to be able to scroll between pages, even if on a page which has vertical scroll)

Is there a way I can do this? can be a css/jquery/ js solution.

code here as can't post without some, but see fiddle:

```
outer-wrapper{
float:left;
width:400px;
height:200px;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.inner-wrapper{
width:800px;
height:200px;
}

.inner-div{
float:left;
width:400px;
height:200px;
display:inline-block;
}

.scrollable-content{
width:200px;
height:200px;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: So you want to scroll vertically when using the scroll wheel of your mouse? (meant to scroll horizontally)

Comment: Do you mean something like metro style?

Comment: not for mousewheel, this is for mobile. Each 'inner-div' is a page, some pages content is longer than the screen so it needs overflow-y:scroll. However, when on a page with this, if I scroll left/right nothing happens, what I want to happen is the outer wrapper to scroll left/right (between pages), but I guess because I'm in a div with only vertical scroll it doesn't allow it?

Comment: Can you specify on which devices/browsers this doesn't work?